# What is the performance cost of MongoDB's .explain() on a query?

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently benchmarking Elasticsearch and MongoDB for a specific use case and want to capture as accurate of a latency metric as possible.

Comment: By "performance cost" do you mean extra overhead for running explain on top of your query?

Comment: Yes the overhead of only the explain

Comment: Would be great if you can share more about your use case and how you plan to use explain(). For example, is your use case heavy?(i.e. process many documents). Are you using the use case very frequently? Are you going to run explain() with every run of your use case? They could be helpful for the community to answer or suggesting other alternatives.

Comment: If you want to benchmark the query, just run the query without explain?